# I use the NUCLEO-L476RG board. ADC runs at 64 MHz and ADC has a 5.33 Msps maximum conversion rate with full resolution

Tags: stm32, adc, sampling, conversion

I need to take 10 samples (10 Hz) per second. How can I set ADC configurations on CubeMX. I use the lowest sampling time (2.5 cycles), but the values I convert and use in ADC change very quickly.

Thanks for helps.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sample at regular time intervals, then use a timer to trigger the ADC:
In ADC_regular_conversion, set external trigger to "Timer X Trigger Out event".
In Trigger output, set trigger event to "Update event".
And set the timer to the desired frequency.

The sampling time value in ADC is how long is the sample&hold capacitor charged, the longer the better. With 10 Sps you can probably use the highest value (ADC clock × (sampling cycles + conversion cycles) < time between two consecutive conversions)